# setState not saving the state

Tags: reactjs, jsx

im trying to set the state of something and its not working component did mount is set to async but when trying the same on my method it said async/await does nothing. this is in a jsx page. I know set state is asynchronous but i thought if componentdidmount was async then all functions called by it are async.

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // states
    this.state = { newObject:"",supra:"",newObject:"",itemName:"",options:"",searchBar:[{locations:["country","region","area","city","neighborhood"]}]};
    this.createNewPage=this.createNewPage.bind(this);
}
```

...

```
 //to search by location.
        async componentDidMount(){
            //set possible options
            let line=new URLSearchParams(window.location.pathname).get("searchCriteria");
             //ignore and skip to else
            if(line!=null){
                let values=line.split(",");
                let newPath="";
                let possibleOptions=[];
                values.map((value,index)=>
                {
                    if(index!=0){
                        newPath+="/"+value;
                    }
                });
          //gets objects form all location type based on new path
            axios.get(
                    'http://localhost:8080/'+"country"+newPath)
                       .then(res => {res.map(e=>{ let keyCode='<MenuWrapper id='+e.id+' name='+e.value+' supra='+null +'/>';
                        possibleOptions.concat(keyCode);});
                        //fix content
                       
                     }).catch(
                     function (error) {
                    });
                axios.get(
                    'http://localhost:8080/'+"region"+newPath)
                       .then(res => {res.map(e=>{ let keyCode='<MenuWrapper id='+e.id+' name='+e.value+' supra='+e.country +'/>';
                        possibleOptions.concat(keyCode);});
                     }).catch(
                     function (error) {
                    });

                axios.get(
                    'http://localhost:8080/'+"area"+newPath)
                       .then(res => {res.map(e=>{ let keyCode='<MenuWrapper id='+e.id+' name='+e.value+' supra='+e.region +'/>';
                       possibleOptions.concat(keyCode);});
                    }).catch(
                     function (error) {
                    });

                    axios.get(
                        'http://localhost:8080/'+"city"+newPath)
                           .then(res => {res.map(e=>{ let keyCode='<MenuWrapper id='+e.id+' name='+e.value+' supra='+e.region +'/>';
                           possibleOptions.concat(keyCode);});
                        }).catch(
                         function (error) {
                        });

                        axios.get(
                          'http://localhost:8080/'+"neighborhood"+newPath)
                             .then(res => {res.map(e=>{ let keyCode='<MenuWrapper id='+e.id+' name='+e.value+' supra='+e.region +'/>';
                             possibleOptions.concat(keyCode);});
                          }).catch(
                           function (error) {
                          });
           
            this.setState({options:possibleOptions});}
            else{
                let id=new URLSearchParams(window.location.pathname).get("id");
                let category=new URLSearchParams(window.location.pathname).get("category");
                let supra="";
                //will set it to country
                if(category===null){
                     await this.setState({type:"country"},() => {
                        console.log(this.state.type);
                      });

                      

                }
                else{
                    this.setState({type:category},() => {
                        console.log(this.state.type)});
                }
                //if id exists get object
                if(id){
                   
                   axios.get(
                    'http://localhost:8080/'+category+'/'+id)
                       .then(res => {
                       this.setState({supra:res});
                     
                     }).catch(
                     function (error) {
                    }); 
                }
                
                //function problem is stuck on.
                 this.createNewPage();

            }
        }
        //content for new object
       createNewPage(){
         
        let keyCode="";
        //will go into this one.
            if(this.state.type==="country"){
                
                keyCode="<div> <b>create a new country: </b><country id=null /></div>";
                //new object does not initialise by  keyCode 
                //
                //

               this.setState({newObject: keyCode }, () => {
                    console.log(this.state.newObject);
                });

                  let x=this.state.newObject;
            }
            else if(this.state.type==="region"){
                keyCode="<div> <b>create a new region:</b><region id=newItem country="+this.state.supra+"/></div>";
              this.setState({newObject:keyCode},() => {
                    console.log(this.state.newObject);
                  });
            }
            else if(this.state.type==="area"){
                keyCode="<div> <b>create a new area: </b><area id=newItem region="+this.state.supra+"/></div>";
                 this.setState({newObject:keyCode},() => {
                    console.log(this.state.newObject);
                  });
            }
            else if(this.state.type==="city"){
                keyCode="<div> <b>create a new city: </b><city id=newItem region="+this.state.supra+"/> </div>";
                 this.setState({newObject:keyCode},() => {
                    console.log(this.state.newObject);
                  });}
            else if(this.state.type==="neighborhood"){
                keyCode="<div> <b>create a new: {this.state.supra}</b><neighborhood id=newItem city="+this.state.supra+"/> </div>";
                this.setState({newObject:keyCode},() => {
                    console.log(this.state.newObject);
                  });
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you want to code waits till a function is done use `await` before it's call `await asyncFunction()` but it does not work on `setState` so you can not write `awate setState()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys it does exactly what i wanted from the start i just didn't have any sleep and was confused why a component called in the string wasn't calling a separate issue, thank you for your help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).